# Preload images using javascript on reload

Tags: javascript, html, web, d3.js

I'm creating a lot of `svg:image`'s with `.attr("xlink:href", "path/to/pic")` in javascript file using d3.js, but it looks like script downloads those pictures over and over on reload. Is there any way to cache pictures on first load and use them on all other reloads/refreshes.

Thanks.

Comment: The browser is most likely caching those requests in the background without you noticing. Each reload after the initial should be slightly faster, depending on the size of the SVG's. Or rather, by "reload" do you mean "redraw", and not a complete page reload?

Comment: I would think that this is more of a Web Server configuration issue. For example, you could instruct the web server - Apache or IIS- to tell the browser to cache the images on the client side. This can be done through sending specific response headers for every image that you want to cache.

Comment: OK, I'll double check that. I was testing things on SimpleHTTPServer, maybe it doesn't cache things, or maybe it's google chrome refreshes the page and cleans the cache. But when I checked on firefox and Apachi it looks like no image reloading. Thanks everyone. I can accept either reply as an answer if you guys don't mind posting it as such.

Comment: That's it! Remote server sends `Not modified`, local server reloads all images. So I guess it's SimpleHTTPServer's flaw. Thanks everyone again. I should've checked that first before posting.